# Android : activity destroy when display turn off

Tags: android

I have a problem with a code becuse when the display turn off the activity was destroy then it restart from onCreate....why ? when the display turn off the activity not must go to onPause??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the life cycle of the Android activity, when an activity becomes background, onPause is called, however, from now on, the system can kill the activity by its will, ie. the system requires more memory.
what you met was normal.

Comment: but my activity is destroid, why ?

Comment: you can read the logcat to find more info. IT'S the system that decides to kill the activity or not, not the developers. IN general, IT'S because more memory are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Is your application in Landscape? if so, check this answer out:
[onDestroy gets called each time the screen goes on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772988/ondestroy-gets-called-each-time-the-screen-goes-on)

Short answer: implement onConfigurationChanged() and change the AndroidManifest.xml file for this activity to: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"